# parent component object is changing without set state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

As for react is concern, we can change the state using using setState ie here setdummyData,
In the below code Parent Component, Initialized dummyData with object header: 2017 and had passed the object to child component and changing the object as dummyData.header = 2018, but parent component object is changing.

May i know the reason behind.

please refer below snippet

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Child from "./Child";

const Parent = () => {
  const [dummyData, setdummyData] = useState({ header: 2017 });
  console.log("-dummyData-", dummyData);
  return <Child dummyData={dummyData} />;
};

export default Parent;

const Child = (props) => {
  let dummyData = props.dummyData;
  dummyData.header = 2018;
  return <div> {dummyData.header} </div>;
};

export default Child;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dummyData` is an Object, and When you do `dummyData.header = 2018;`, it changes the Object `dummyData`, therefore in parent the header value is changed.

Always update the state using `setState` function, this will cause re-render of the component and its children, when state changes

Answer (score 0):

You must always use setState to change state and not change props or state directly.

Comment: will it change the object,if we change it directly

Comment: It goes against React best practices. If you need to change it from the child you can pass a function to the child that changes the state of the parent, and reference the prop in the child, which should be read only.

Answer (score 0):

You should never mutate state directly as it might not even cause a re-render if you update the state with the same object reference.

You can give a function as first argument to setValues just like you are used to in the class component setState, and that function in turn will get the correct state as argument, and what is returned will be the new state.

```
const Parent = () => {
    const [dummy, setDummy] = useState({ header: 2017 });
    return <Child dummyData={dummyData} setDummy={setDummy} />;
};

export default Parent;

const Child = props => {
    props.dummyData({ ...props.dummyData , 2018});
    return <div> {props.dummyData.header} </div>;
};
```